# SCSS - Loop while adding text

Tags: sass

In my SCSS file I have this:

```
@for $i from 1 to 100 {
    $percent  : $i + '%';
    
      [fxFlex='$percent'] {
      flex: 1 1 $percent ;
  }
}
```

I want 1%, then 2% etc but I get this. I wish to remove the double quotes and have $percent display as 1%, 2% not $percent:

```
[fxFlex=' $percent '] {
    flex: 1 1 "1%";
}

[fxFlex=' $percent '] {
    flex: 1 1 "2%";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

1. You need to use variable interpolation,  meaning you have to write `#{$percent}` instead of `$percent`:

> Interpolation can be used almost anywhere in a Sass stylesheet to embed the result of a SassScript expression into a chunk of CSS. Just wrap an expression in #{} in any of the following places:

[Source: sass-lang](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)

2. Second thing, you probably want to remove the quotes in the flex property. You can do it with the string function `string.unquote()`, but first you need to import it with the `use` keyword.

```css
@use "sass:string";

@for $i from 1 to 100 {
  $percent: $i + '%';
  
  [fxFlex='#{$percent}'] {
    flex: 1 1 string.unquote($percent);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was a kind and excellent answer.